# How to initialise a C struct array within a class

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, arduino, initialization

I'm writing an Arduino library in C and I'm struggling how to initialise an array of structs.

I currently have this as my `Menu.h` file

```
#ifndef MENU_H
#define MENU_H

#if defined(ARDUINO) && ARDUINO >= 100
    #include "Arduino.h"
#else
    #include "WProgram.h"
#endif

struct menuItem_t {
    char heading[16];
    char item[16];
    configItem_t* configItem;
};

class menu_t {
    public:
        menu_t();
        void test();
        menuItem_t _items[];
    private:

};

#endif
```

In `Menu.cpp` file I've tried various ways to initialise this array but none seem to work (i.e. the array is never populated)

```
#include "Menu.h"

menu_t::menu_t(){

}

void menu_t::test(){
    Serial.println("test:");
    Serial.println((sizeof(_items)/sizeof(_items[0])));
    Serial.println("first heading:");
    Serial.println(_items[0].heading);
}

menuItem_t _items[] = { 
    {"TIME", "", NULL},
    {"H", "Hour", NULL},
    {"M", "Minute", NULL},
};
```

This test always returns BLANK `sketch.ino`:

```
#include "Menu.h"

menu_t m;

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println("Started...");
    m.test();
}

void loop(){

}
```

I've tested the code in the non OO way and it appears to work OK.  I'm struggling with the language :(
The weird thing is I managed to get this code working somehow, got excited, deleted some code and then it stopped working.  I know I'm close!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this is C? C doesn't have classes.

Comment: "deleted some code and then it stopped working". Look into version control.

Comment: I didn't check it in when it was working :(

Comment: The Arduino compiler supports a subset of C++  It's not a full C++ implementation and there's no `new` keyword.

Comment: "A subset of C++" is not C. And please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I'm not able to edit my question but here is the full header

Comment: I'm cautious to call this a C++ question as the underlying avr-g++ compiler doesn't support all of C++ 

http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=2249.0

Comment: The only code not shown in my heading file is
`#ifndef MENU_H
#define MENU_H` 

and 
`#endif`

Comment: You should always be able to edit your own question. And a complete header file is not a [mcve].

Comment: I found the edit button so updated with a full example.

Comment: `menuItem_t _items[];` is an error in C++. You should specify the dimension at that point

Comment: Please clarify whether you intend each instance of  a `menu_t` to have its own copy of `_items`

Comment: @M.M Declaring menuItem_t _items[] does create a blank struct array of that size but it is not populated by Menu.cpp

Comment: @MrMase I doubt it creates a "blank struct array" of any size other than 0

Comment: @M.M there should only be 1 menu_t object in memory and only 1 copy of items is required.  I haven't tried making static members yet as was hoping to get the basics working first.

Comment: @M.M Declaring menuItem_t _items[3] does create a struct array of that size but it is still not populated by Menu.cpp.

Comment: @MrMase you need to add code into the constructor or a member function to populate the array.  Your line `menuItem_t _items[] = {` declares a variable `_items` that is unrelated to any object's class member

Comment: @M.M I can see that how makes sense but how do I go about it?  If I put `menuItem_t _items[] = {` in the constructor surely it will create a local variable within the method called _items?

Comment: You could do that and then use a loop to assign each element of the class member array from the local array. There are many ways to approach this

Comment: @M.M I would like to avoid looping if possible to keep, how do I reference the member array `_items[]` in the constructor without creating another local copy?

Comment: You can put the whole initializer in the ctor-initializer list. It would probably help you to learn some basic about c++ initialization by consulting reference material

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of banging my heading head to get it work I've decided to make the array a private static member.  This solves the initialization issue I was having and I don't have to specify the number of elements in the array.

```
#ifndef MENU_H
#define MENU_H

#if defined(ARDUINO) && ARDUINO >= 100
    #include "Arduino.h"
#else
    #include "WProgram.h"
#endif

struct menuItem_t {
    char heading[16];
    char item[16];
    configItem_t* configItem;
};

class menu_t {
    public:
        menu_t();
        void test();
    private:
        static menuItem_t _items[];
};

#endif
```

Here is the .cpp

```
#include "Menu.h"

menu_t::menu_t(){

}

void menu_t::test(){
    Serial.println("test:");
    Serial.println((sizeof(_items)/sizeof(_items[0])));
    Serial.println("first heading:");
    Serial.println(_items[0].heading);
}

menuItem_t menu_t::_items[] = { 
    {"TIME", "", NULL},
    {"H", "Hour", NULL},
    {"M", "Minute", NULL},
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems. First, you're not giving a dimension to your array. This is a zero-length array, which is not permitted in standard C++ but allowed as an extension by many compilers. This allocates no space for the array, but assumes you will use the class or struct as an overlay to interpret properly allocated memory of sufficient size. You are doing no such allocation.

Second, your attempted initialization is not initializing your member variable at all, but creating a separate array.

To correct your code, you must provide a dimension to the array and use a member initializer in the constructor. Here's an example, but using standard C++ since I don't have Arduino C++. I can't guarantee that it will work for Arduino, but it should at least get you closer:

```
#include <iostream>

struct configItem_t;

struct menuItem_t {
    char heading[16];
    char item[16];
    configItem_t* configItem;
};

class menu_t {
    public:
        menu_t();
        void test();
        menuItem_t _items[3];
    private:

};

menu_t::menu_t() :
        _items{
          { "TIME", "", NULL },
          { "H", "Hour", NULL },
          { "M", "Minute", NULL }
        }
{
    // Empty implementation
}

void menu_t::test(){
//    Serial.println("test:");
//    Serial.println((sizeof(_items)/sizeof(_items[0])));
//    Serial.println("first heading:");
//    Serial.println(_items[0].heading);
    std::cout << "test:\n";
    std::cout << (sizeof(_items)/sizeof(_items[0])) << '\n';
    std::cout << "first heading:\n";
    std::cout << _items[0].heading << '\n';
}

//menuItem_t _items[] = {
//    {"TIME", "", NULL},
//    {"H", "Hour", NULL},
//    {"M", "Minute", NULL},
//};

int main()
{
    menu_t m;
    m.test();
}
```

Output:

```
test:
3
first heading:
TIME
```

If you really don't know the size array you need until run time, you will have to use dynamic allocation with `new` or `malloc` (my Googling suggests that `new` is indeed available with Arduino C++, but dynamic allocation is not generally recommended).

Comment: Thanks Fred!  This works fine but I've decided to implement the approach outlined in my posted answer (i.e. define the array as static).  By using that approach I don't need need to specify the array size, which is great as there are a few items.